# Using PrincipalSearcher to find users with "or" parameters

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Is it possible to use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher` to search based on multiple parameters using "or" (not "and").

i.e.

```
// This uses an and
//(&(objectCategory=person)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(&(SAMAccountName=tom*)(DisplayName=tom*)))
var searchPrinciple = new UserPrincipal(context);
searchPrinciple.DisplayName =  "tom*";
searchPrinciple.SamAccountName = "tom*";

var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
searcher.QueryFilter = searchPrinciple;

var results = searcher.FindAll();
```

and I would like a search similar to this (in LDAP) using `PrincipalSearcher` (not `DirectorySearcher`)

```
// (&(objectCategory=person)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|(SAMAccountName=tom*)(DisplayName=tom*)))
```

Answer (score 26):

It's obviously not possible, here is a workaround:

```
List<UserPrincipal> searchPrinciples = new List<UserPrincipal>();
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { DisplayName="tom*"});
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { SamAccountName = "tom*" });
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { MiddleName = "tom*" });
searchPrinciples.Add(new UserPrincipal(context) { GivenName = "tom*" });

List<Principal> results = new List<Principal>();
var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
foreach (var item in searchPrinciples)
{
    searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(item);
    results.AddRange(searcher.FindAll());
}
```

Comment: You will have to handle duplicates using this. If the display name, given name and account name all contain the name "tom" you will have duplicates.

Comment: I was wanting this as well, though at the point of multiple queries is it significantly less performant? I wonder why I shouldn't just fall back to the DirectorySearcher if it can't be done with PrincipalSearcher

Answer (score 8):

Not necessarily as clean as some of the other answers but here is how I've implemented this in a project I'm working on.  I wanted both searches to be run async to try and reduce any slow down due to running two AD queries.

```
public async static Task<List<ADUserEntity>> FindUsers(String searchString)
{
    searchString = String.Format("*{0}*", searchString);
    List<ADUserEntity> users = new List<ADUserEntity>();

    using (UserPrincipal searchMaskDisplayname = new UserPrincipal(domainContext) { DisplayName = searchString })
    using (UserPrincipal searchMaskUsername = new UserPrincipal(domainContext) { SamAccountName = searchString })
    using (PrincipalSearcher searcherDisplayname = new PrincipalSearcher(searchMaskDisplayname))
    using (PrincipalSearcher searcherUsername = new PrincipalSearcher(searchMaskUsername))
    using (Task<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>> taskDisplayname = Task.Run<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>>(() => searcherDisplayname.FindAll()))
    using (Task<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>> taskUsername = Task.Run<PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>>(() => searcherUsername.FindAll()))
    {
        foreach (UserPrincipal userPrincipal in (await taskDisplayname).Union(await taskUsername))
            using (userPrincipal)
            {
                users.Add(new ADUserEntity(userPrincipal));
            }
    }

    return users.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

My ADUserEntity class has an equality check based on the SID. I tried to add the `Distinct()` on to the `Union()` of the two searcher results but that didn't work.

I welcome any constructive criticism on my answer as I'd like to know if there is any way I can improve it.

Comment: To get only distinct users returned, you can use LINQ to group by an identifier (e.g. SID): Replace `return users.Distinct().ToList();` with `return users.GroupBy(user => user.Sid).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();`

Comment: What about using a simple if-statement before adding the ADUserEntity object to the collection? if (!users.Contains(userPrincipal) users.Add(new ADUserEntity(userPrincipal));

Answer (score 4):

I know this is kind of late, but this is the construct I use when searching AD:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<SomeUserModelClass>> GetUsers(//Whatever filters you want)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(context);
        principal.Enabled = true;
        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(principal);

        var users = searcher.FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>()
            .Where(x => x.SomeProperty... // Perform queries)
            .Select(x => new SomeUserModelClass
            {
                userName = x.SamAccountName,
                email = x.UserPrincipalName,
                guid = x.Guid.Value
            }).OrderBy(x => x.userName).AsEnumerable();

        return users;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are basically reading the entire directory, and performing the filtering in the client. This won't scale for any medium sized directory and bigger.

Comment: I've since added, before executing the search, filtering to the UserPrincipal object and narrowing down the scope of the search to a specific starting OU.

Answer (score -3):

> The FindAll method searches the domain specified in the principal
>   context **for objects that have identical properties to those set on the
>   query filter**. The FindAll method returns all objects that match the
>   supplied object whereas the FindOne method returns only a single
>   matching principal object.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384378(v=vs.90).aspx

I don't know what you need, but you could do a search by 1 proprety and 1 by other and then use LINQ on the lists to merge,filter and etc...

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I am currently using, I was hoping there would be a way to do this more cleanly, in one search. Thanks though.

Answer (score -5):

```
PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName);
GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pContext, "Administrators");
bool isMember = UserPrincipal.Current.IsMemberOf(gp);
```