# Search AD only having SID

Tags: c#, active-directory

is there a way to search the Active Directory using UserPrincipal only having the SID?
I have the SID in byte[] (previously queried with DirectorySearcher) and used a StringBuilder to convert it to "S-1-15-..." and "\01\05..".

I tried to handle it this way:

```
PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal pUser = new UserPrincipal(pContext);
pUser.Sid = stringBuilder.ToString();
PrincipalSearcher pSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
pSearcher.QueryFilter = pUser;
Console.WriteLine(pSearcher.FindOne().DistinguishedName.ToString());
```

Visual Studio tells me, that the Sid is write protected. Of course...

Thanks in advance & Cheers
Alex

p.s.: I already tried to solve it the way described here: [How can I convert from a SID to an account name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499053/how-can-i-convert-from-a-sid-to-an-account-name-in-c-sharp), but no success here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly can. I use the below method to find my users in an internal application called "Atlas". Please excuse the formatting.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN_NAME_IMPORTANT"))
{
    var userIdentity = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "USER GUID GOES HERE"));
}
```

Comment: It's very important to use the overload for the principalcontext that includes the "DOMAIN_NAME". If you don't do this, there's an issue with .NET which occasionally throws exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Better late than never. Your question helped me along, so I thought I would try to add completeness to this answer for posterity. Note that my context was Local Machine, for which `FindByIdentity` is too slow.

You were on the right trail. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725273/3757184) particularly helpful to use LINQ to specify the search parameters in the collection returned by the `PrincipalSearcher`. These queries did the trick for me to quickly find the accounts via SID:

```
private static GroupPrincipal GetGroup(string accountSid)
{
  PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();
  GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);
  return new PrincipalSearcher(oGroupPrincipal).FindAll().Cast<GroupPrincipal>()
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sid.Value.Equals(accountSid, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}

private static UserPrincipal GetUser(string accountSid)
{
  PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();
  UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);
  return new PrincipalSearcher(oUserPrincipal).FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>()
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sid.Value.Equals(accountSid, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}

private static PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
{
  return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName);
}
```

For further details, see my [post](http://www.codingmatter.com/coding/2016/11/21/fast-active-directory-lookup-with-sid.html) on this subject.

Comment: I tried this in a domain with more than 16000 accounts and FindAll with the query is still 20x faster than FindByIdentity.